# Firebase-admin Python SDK Notification with Channel ID

Tags: python, firebase-admin

admin SDK. I want to know how to set the Channel Id on the Notification? I saw in Legacy Http Server Protocol has a parameter "android_channel_id", but in the SDK, Notification, or Android_Config, I don't see the way to set the channel id. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I found that I have to use AndroidConfig and AndroidNotification Objects to construct the message. On the Android Notification Object that is an attribute channel_id to set the channel info.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).